# Using Salesforce Metadata API can we create/update 'Branding Set' with the respective 'Lightning Experience Theme'? If so how?

Tags: lightning-experience, metadata-api, theme-branding

1. Using 'BrandingSet' Metadata API I am able to create a New Branding Set, along with the necessary Property Values & Images. But to enable the Branding Set so that it's visible in the UI found out that we require another Metadata API namely 'Lightning Experience Theme'.
2. But after several attempts I was not able to crack the part where we can create the Lightning Experience theme post Branding Set creation using Metadata API.
3. It would be helpful if anyone can list out the sequence of steps to be followed to achieve this!

Comment: Yes @identigral, Thank you for your suggestion.
But we are not using any Experience Cloud. What kind of approach can be followed if it is generic not specific to Experience cloud. If you have further info on the metadata structure which can be used for me to update/create the Lightning Experience Theme.

Comment: @Blake The doc says BrandingSet [is specifically for Experience Cloud](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_brandingset.htm).  I'm curious what use case you have for it outside of Expererience Cloud.